# Justify determinant using properties of determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'd like to understand how to prove that the determinant of the matrix below is zero, without actually calculating it, just based on the determinant properties

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x & y & z \\
    z+y & z+x & x+y \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

I searched everywhere for but couldn't find a question like mine, so if it's duplicate, I apologize in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding row two to row one doesn't affect the determinant, so it equals
$$\begin{vmatrix}
    x+y+z & x+y+z & x+y+z \\
    z+y & z+x & x+y \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}.$$
If one row is a multiple of another, the determinant is zero.

Comment: Equivalently, the row vector $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & {-x-y-z} \end{bmatrix}$ is in the left nullspace of the matrix.